# How to used woocommerce ajax filter for filtring Custom Post Type?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, filtering

I have used this plugin **https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/** for product filtration,

### Q- Can we do Filtration of Custom Post Type with this plugin ?

I want to filter the custom posts on the bases of **Custom Fields of Custom post Type**.

If we can't do with this plugin, Then Please give me suggestions for alternate option.

Comment: May i know what's the problem @BilalAhmed ?

Comment: Yes, this can be done but will require some custom code

Comment: Please check this theme :
http://education.themerex.net/

i want filter on course page 
as like shop page drop-down